# SQL count distinct values by delemiter

Tags: sql, r, sqlite, aggregation

I have a data set that looks like:

```
   Fruit Quantity 
    apple 1/2
    apple 2/2
    apple 2/2
    orange 1/3
    orange 1/1
    orange 2/10
    grape 4/10`
```

the first number refers to the crate each of the fruits are in. This is a massive data set and I want a sql code that could aggregate how many crates each fruit has.

I have tried count in many different ways but have not been able to identify the first number in the data set. I have also tried many r packages including ply and data.table to figure this out but have had no luck yet any ideas using those tools or any other r packages would be appreciated.

Any thoughts?

to clarify
My desired output would look like this

```
fruit count
apple 2
orange 2
grape 1
```

---

looking for an answer using sqlite

Comment: Yeah one would be to include the many different ways you've tried.

Comment: So, I've got a quick answer, but the final product depends on the desired outcome. Can you edit your answer using the 5 sample rows here to show what you want to come of the query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use string operations to get the parts of the strings, then group on the fruit and cound how many different crate numbers there are.

For a table `ShippingRecords` with the field `Shipping` that would be:

```
select Fruit, count(distinct Crate)
from (
  select
    Fruit = left(Shipping, charindex(' ', Shipping) - 1),
    Crate = substring(Shipping, charindex(' ', Shipping) + 1, charindex('/', Shipping) - charindex(' ', Shipping) - 1)
  from ShippingRecords
) y
group by Fruit
```

Result:

```
apple    2
grape    1
orange   2
```

SQL Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/0730b/1

---

If `Fruit` and `Quantity` are separate fields, then it gets a bit simpler:

```
select Fruit, count(distinct Crate)
from (
  select
    Fruit,
    Crate = left(Quantity, charindex('/', Quantity) - 1)
  from ShippingRecords
) y
group by Fruit
```

SQL Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/51bf5/3

---

#### Edit:

With SQLite you use the `substr` and `instr` functions:

```
select Fruit, count(*)
from (
  select distinct
    Fruit,
    Crate = substr(Quantity, 1, instr(Quantity, '/') - 1)
  from ShippingRecords
) y
group by Fruit
```

Comment: Hey Guffa can you confirm what you used for row column names? Thanks!

Comment: @user3609179: The table name is `ShippingRecords` and the column name is `Shipping`.

Comment: thanks again! Do you have an idea on an equivalent to charindex that would work in sqlite?

Comment: @user3609179: Use the `instr` function.

Comment: would it be the same format just instr instead of charindex?

Comment: @user3609179: No, you have to swap the parameters. `charindex(x, y)` is the same as `instr(y, x)`. The return value has the exact same meaning.

Comment: ok thanks. Could would you mind updating your answer with instr?

Comment: @user3609179: Sure. You also need to use `substr` instead of `left`, it's in the code above.

Comment: hey I am getting a error that says.  Exception Name: NS_ERROR_FAILURE
Exception Message: Component returned failure code: 0x80004005 (NS_ERROR_FAILURE) [mozIStorageConnection.createStatement] any ideas?

Comment: @user3609179: It seems SQLite doesn't support `count distinct`, you can try to use `distinct` in the subquery intead. I edited the code above.

Answer (score 0):

Get the name and fraction separate by using right and left (done this way in case there are fruit names with spaces in them). Then split the fraction in the same manner. Presuming a column named fruits in a table named denormalizedFruits:

```
select Fruit
  , left(Crates, charindex('/',Crates) - 1) as ReportedCrate
  , right(Crates, charindex('/',reverse(Crates))-1) as ReportedTotalCrates
  , count(*)over(partition by Fruit) as CratesInDatabse
from (
  select left(fruit,charindex(' ',fruit)-1) as Fruit
    ,right(fruit,charindex(' ',reverse(fruit))-1) as Crates
  from denormalizedFruit
  ) f
```

Check it out at [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/cde0e/6).

Comment: Hi Jaaz. Can you confirm what you used from the original data for the column names. I understand what you did in SQLFiddle. But what did you use for the column names from my original data? Thanks!

Comment: Also I am not sure if this works exactly. I edited the input data take a look.

Comment: @user3609179 Your question did not have any column names defined. Thus, I created "fruit" in my table to represent the set of strings you posted. If this is not correct, please be more clear about your schema when posting a question, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Below sql will return the exact result you wanted to achieve.
I am assuming the following:

**Table Name:** Stock 
**Columns:** Fruit, Quantity

You might need to chage the column names.

## SQL:

```
SELECT Fruit, COUNT(Crates) AS [Count] FROM 
(
    SELECT DISTINCT Fruit, 
           STUFF(Quantity,                                  -- Main String
                 CHARINDEX( '/',Quantity),                  -- Start
                (LEN(Quantity)-CHARINDEX( '/',Quantity)+1), -- Length
                 ''                                         -- Replace with empty string
                 ) AS Crates  
    FROM [Stock]
) As Wrap
GROUP BY Fruit
ORDER BY [Count] DESC
```